# Command to get the total count for every second

Tags: linux

```
       20210527 15:20:46.014 [DEBUG] SmsCounter[main] Multiple sms detected , Sms Count : 4
       20210527 15:20:46.024 [DEBUG] SmsCounter[main] Multiple sms detected , Sms Count : 2
       20210527 15:20:46.024 [DEBUG] SmsCounter[main] Multiple sms detected , Sms Count : 4
       20210527 15:20:46.024 [DEBUG] SmsCounter[main] Multiple sms detected , Sms Count : 2
       20210527 15:20:46.024 [DEBUG] SmsCounter[main] Multiple sms detected , Sms Count : 4
       20210527 15:20:46.024 [DEBUG] SmsCounter[main] Multiple sms detected , Sms Count : 2
```

I have something like this in my file, How do I get count in such a way that I have many similar records for all seconds with milli-seconds and I get total sms count for every second like for 15:20:46, 15:20:47 and 15:20:48 ?

I want the output

```
15:20:46 sum=xx
15:20:47 sum=xx
15:20:48 sum=xx
```

Comment: Silly? You post a question with totally messed formatting. I correct it. And your revert it?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
myfile=<FILEPATH>
total_count=0

while read line; do
    currenttime="$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')" 
    count="$(echo $line | awk '{print $NF}')"
    # echo -e "${currenttime%.*}\t${count}"
    total_count+=$count
done < "$myfile"
echo $total_count
```

Comment: using the above method, im getting outuput  as                                                       
20210527        4
20210527        2
20210527        4
20210527        2
20210527        4
20210527        2  But I want  sum of the count so that for 15:20:46 I get 18 (4+2+4+2+4+2), for 15:20:47 I get another sum count

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using perl. If your log lines are in txt.txt

```
perl -e '$h;while (<>){if (/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{3}.*:\s(\d+)/){$h{$1}=$h{$1}+$2}} foreach $k (sort keys %h) {print "$k $h{$k}\n"}' txt.txt
```

Output:
`15:20:46 18`

What this does:

```
perl -e '$h; #initialise a hash
while (<>) # iterate over txt.txt line by line
{
if (/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{3}.*:\s(\d+)/) #Capture the time without the millis as $1 and the count as $2
    {
    $h{$1}=$h{$1}+$2 #Store the cumulative count against the seconds
    }
}
foreach $k (sort keys %h) 
{
 print "$k $h{$k}\n" #print seconds and count
}' txt.txt
```